# How to innerHTML an HTML tag without id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="root">
        <div id="content">
            <span>
                <title>My SVG Example Title</title>
                <ellipse id="svg_1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I innerHTML the `<span>` tag without changing the `<title>` tag using jQuery?
So my expected output would be something like this:

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="root">
        <div id="content">
            <span>
                <title>My SVG Example Title</title>
                <input type="text" value="this is the innerHTML I must insert but how?" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there a title tag inside the span? @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#canvas')
 .find('span')
 .contents()
 .not('title')
 .replaceWith($('<input />', {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'this is the innerHTML I must insert but how?'
 }));
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks jAndy and to all who replied :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
var newHtml = '<input type="text" value="NewStuff!" />';

$("#svg_1").after(newHtml).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ellipse` element and add your `input` element:

```
$("#content span ellipse").remove()
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("value", "foo");
$("#content span").append(input);
```

Comment: well, you're right. but he didn't mentioned that the structure is always like this.